# Dynamic element Bootstrap in ASPX web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I need to have a row with three textbox and one checkbox. And it is in a div with certain width. Refer to the picture below.

[image]

How to **create those as a dynamic element** in ASPX web form? I want to **use Bootstrap** in styling. I dont know whether normal Javascript or jQuery could give me the simpler code to create this dynamic field. Really need your helps! Thanks.

If got any link for me to refer, Im really appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: what do you mean by a dynamic element? you are using some kind of .net server side control? like a data repeater? or you are creating the row in javascript?

Comment: Right now, Im creating new row in javascript. in client-side only. Not creating in code behind, the server-side. @BryanDellinger

Comment: If you create html controls at client-side only, you wont' be able to retrieve posted values back at server-side. Before working on styles, you need to take care of the main issue.

Comment: @Win , I'm not trying to retrieve the value, right now. Just want to create a new row only plus using Bootstrap on styling. And it is a dummy web site afterall. I just want to get the concept and idea only. Hope you can help.

Comment: as Win22 mentioned adding these rows via javascript makes it difficult to interact with the values in the aspx code behind. the Way I have overcome this is one use a web method and process with an ajax call, or the way I do it is include web api in your project and process using the web api controller

Comment: I see.. so @BryanDellinger . I'll wait for your answer then. Thanks for giving some advice on it.

Comment: I already answered.  currently it is the only answer, is  there an additional question?

Comment: nope @BryanDellinger. thanks.

Comment: I apologize I THOUGHT I had posted my answer but I forgot to hit post answer so I did not. sorry about that, it is there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a javascript solution (I used one of the many mvvm client side libraries to make it easy)

```js
function row() {
  var self = this;
  this.checkbox = ko.observable('')
  this.textbox1 = ko.observable('');
  this.textbox2 = ko.observable('');
  this.textbox3 = ko.observable('');
}

function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.rowArray = ko.observableArray('');
  this.addRow = function() {
    self.rowArray.push(new row());
  }
  this.remove = function(row) {
    self.rowArray.remove(row);
  }
}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: rowArray">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="checkbox col-xs-1">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: checkbox">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3>
      <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: textbox1" />
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3>
      <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: textbox2" />
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-3>
      <input class="form-control" data-bind="textInput: textbox3" />
    </div>
    <div class=col-xs-2>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: addRow">
  Add Row
</button>
```